# How to get multidimensional array element data by having it's path in string?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have such code:

```
$data = [];
$data['key1']['key2']['key3'] = 123;
```

and then, I need to get data from this array is such or similar way:

```
$path = "['key1']['key2']['key3']";
echo $data[$path];  # should return 123
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you tried anything or should we just write your code?!

Comment: How are you building the string up in the first place?

Comment: PHP arrays don't work like that - you can't do it this way. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: If you know the key names such that you can put them in the string, then you should just access the array properly instead of with a special string.

Comment: 2 Rizier123: yes, i've tried to solve this by creating simple class and use __get function, but still nothing.

Comment: $path is index of your 1D array. it will work `$path = "['key1']['key2']['key3']";$data[$path]='xx'; echo $data[$path]` but `$data[$path]!=$data['key1']['key2']['key3']` `(1D!=3D)`